# How to delete n messages from a channel?

Tags: discord.js

I am working on a discord bot. I want to implement a feature like Tatsumaki's t!prune 5 (deletes 5 messages from the history).

Okay, lemme show you what I mean one way or another:

```
msg.channel.delete(2); // 2 is the number of messages being deleted.
                       // this is not a real function, just an example
```

Is there such a thing like what I showed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following

```
const fetchedMessages = await msg.channel.fetchMessages();
const amount = 50 // number of messages that should be deleted (max 50 otherwise you have to change the option limit property for .fetchMessages())



for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
await fetchedMessages[i].delete()
}
```

---

You could also use the `.bulkDelete()` function:

```
await msg.channel.bulkDelete(AMOUNT)
```

Comment: do i need to add `async` to the function? (`async deleteMessage(msg)`, for example)

Comment: Yea because it‘s a promise @Ad2017

Comment: I added another method to my answer which could solve your issue

Comment: oh.. thats what i was looking for. simple and short. thank you.

Comment: I think the for loop `i <` should be `i < amount`, also there is a ratelimit on `.delete()` with a limit of 3 so the loop would cause a ratelimit hell